# Podcast #2: RIM Playbook, Continuous Client, Coda

Tags: discussion, podcast-episode

This is the second episode of the Ask Different Podcast, an unofficial podcast created by members of the Ask Different community about Apple and related technologies.

Your hosts for this episode once again are [Kyle Cronin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin), [Jason Salaz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1346/vxjasonxv), and [Nathan Greenstein](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2220/nathan).

- Jason and Kyle begin with news of [Stack Exchange’s improved <strike>tag sets</strike> filters tool](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/), which makes it easier to view your combined profile and follow subjects that interest you across the entire Stack Exchange network.
- Newly-released [white iPhone 4](http://www.apple.com/iphone/): Thicker? We discuss the (late) release of the white iPhone 4 and the girth it’s apparently gained.
- Jason shares his experience using RIM’s [BlackBerry Playbook](http://us.blackberry.com/playbook-tablet/) tablet. It’s effective, and it fits in, but is it enough?
- More iPhone tracking! We discuss what’s recently come to light about the Great iPhone Tracking Scandal, including [Apple’s official press release](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/04/27location_qa.html) and the action it promises.

  - Apple’s claim: It isn’t tracking!
  - An upcoming [software update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1358) will reduce size of location database, and stop syncing it to computers.
- Jason and Kyle discuss [Marco Arment’s experience](http://www.marco.org/2011/04/28/removed-instapaper-free) with having free and paid versions of the Instapaper app on the iOS App Store, and share their own views about free vs. paid apps.
- Nathan brings news of the new, controversial [AirPush](http://www.airpush.com/) advertising service for Android. We share our views on what is and isn’t acceptable in mobile advertising and in-app purchasing.
- Kyle shares his support for the idea of a [Continuous Client](http://www.engadget.com/2010/05/26/a-modest-proposal-the-continuous-client/), a mechanism to let you pick up on one device exactly where you left off on another one. We share our experiences with various products’ and services’ good and bad support for this concept.
- Our App of the Week is [Coda](http://panic.com/coda), one window web development, by Panic. Coda is available on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coda/id406001464?mt=12), and a trial version can be downloaded from [Panic's site](http://panic.com/coda/).

This episode was recorded on Saturday, April 30th. You can subscribe to this podcast via [RSS](http://feeds.feedburner.com/AskDifferentPodcast) or [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/id435683997). If you have any feedback or questions you’d like for us to answer on air, leave a comment on this post or e-mail us at podcast@askdifferent.net.

[Download](http://media.podcast.askdifferent.net/2.mp3)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to personally apologize for some of my word and term transpositions in this episode. And I'd also like to personally thank Kyle for putting up with my sniffles, coughs, and all the rest. He did a really great job of filtering all that stuff out to make a much better listening experience!

I blame sickness :). It's a worthwhile scapegoat.

Comment: http://images.icanhascheezburger.com/completestore/2008/9/2/escapegoatis128648410209322532.jpg

Comment: ^^ ROLF!!! Very appropriate.

Comment: Not in here, mister. This is a Mercedes.